# Azure B2C - Custom Policy - Error connecting identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've been trying to add a custom policy for Azure AD B2C to connect with [Autodesk Forge](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/overview/), following steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom?tabs=applications.

I modified the bit for Facebook's `ClaimsProvider` with the following:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
      <!-- The following Domain element allows this profile to be used if the request comes with domain_hint 
           query string parameter, e.g. domain_hint=facebook.com  -->
      <Domain>autodesk.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>AutodeskForge</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="FORGE-OAUTH">
          <!-- The text in the following DisplayName element is shown to the user on the claims provider 
               selection screen. -->
          <DisplayName>Forge</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://developer.api.autodesk.com/userprofile/v1/users/@me</Item>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">AutodeskForge</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">0</Item>

            <!-- The Facebook required HTTP GET method, but the access token response is in JSON format from 3/27/2017 -->
            <Item Key="AccessTokenResponseFormat">json</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimsEndpointFormat">json</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ForgeSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="userId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="firstName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="lastName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="userName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="emailId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="autodesk.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

And also replaced the claims provider id on the user journey from `Facebook-OAUTH` to `FORGE_OAUTH`.

When run, it does redirect to Autodesk Forge authorize endpoint properly, but then it fails when trying to connect to the `identity provider`, returning the below error:

```
AADB2C90289: We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.
Correlation ID: 188d934d-f1f0-48c5-98c4-917b032b94d2
Timestamp: 2019-11-29 10:54:49Z
```

[Error Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPHr1.gif)

I'm not very experienced with AAD B2C, but it seems I might just being missing one step at some point.

When adding Application Insight, the `trace` log outputs this:

```
[
  {
    "Kind": "Headers",
    "Content": {
      "UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint": "urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights",
      "CorrelationId": "99e13295-a206-449c-b011-a33422112b29",
      "EventInstance": "Event:ClaimsExchange",
      "TenantId": "alvarob2c.onmicrosoft.com",
      "PolicyId": "B2C_1A_signup_signin"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Transition",
    "Content": {
      "EventName": "ClaimsExchange",
      "StateName": "Initial"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.ClaimsExchangeMessageValidationHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Transition",
    "Content": {
      "EventName": "ClaimsExchange",
      "StateName": "Microsoft.Cpim.Protocols.PartnerProtocolException"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsPartnerErrorReachesMaximumRetriesHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "Statebag": {
        "MACHSTATE": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:31.6899756Z",
          "k": "MACHSTATE",
          "v": "Microsoft.Cpim.Protocols.PartnerProtocolException",
          "p": true
        },
        "JC": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.797697Z",
          "k": "JC",
          "v": "en-US",
          "p": true
        },
        "ORCH_CS": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.953952Z",
          "k": "ORCH_CS",
          "v": "2",
          "p": true
        },
        "ORCH_IDX": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.953952Z",
          "k": "ORCH_IDX",
          "v": "0",
          "p": true
        },
        "RA": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.953952Z",
          "k": "RA",
          "v": "0",
          "p": true
        },
        "RPP": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.797697Z",
          "k": "RPP",
          "v": "OAUTH2",
          "p": true
        },
        "RPIPP": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.797697Z",
          "k": "RPIPP",
          "v": "OAuth2ProtocolProvider",
          "p": true
        },
        "OTID": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.797697Z",
          "k": "OTID",
          "v": "alvarob2c.onmicrosoft.com",
          "p": true
        },
        "IC": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.9383272Z",
          "k": "IC",
          "v": "True",
          "p": true
        },
        "MSG(283863a3-02dd-4c87-b4ae-2500a398fed4)": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.9383272Z",
          "k": "MSG(283863a3-02dd-4c87-b4ae-2500a398fed4)",
          "v": "{\"TenantId\":\"alvarob2c.onmicrosoft.com\",\"PolicyId\":\"B2C_1A_signup_signin\",\"RedirectUri\":\"https://jwt.ms/\",\"AdditionalParameters\":{\"p\":\"B2C_1A_signup_signin\"},\"Nonce\":\"defaultNonce\",\"ClientId\":\"4b03fe96-24d9-40b5-b01d-c45b95422b31\",\"ResponseType\":\"id_token\",\"ResponseRedirector\":{\"URI\":\"https://jwt.ms\",\"D\":false,\"WF\":true,\"R\":false},\"Scope\":\"openid\",\"AppModelVersion\":1,\"ScopedProviders\":[]}",
          "p": true,
          "t": "OAuth2"
        },
        "IMESSAGE": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.9383272Z",
          "k": "IMESSAGE",
          "v": "283863a3-02dd-4c87-b4ae-2500a398fed4",
          "p": true
        },
        "TAGE": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:31.5024363Z",
          "k": "TAGE",
          "v": "ForgeExchange",
          "p": true
        },
        "SE": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:27.953952Z",
          "k": "SE",
          "v": "Social",
          "p": true
        },
        "CMESSAGE": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:31.3461838Z",
          "k": "CMESSAGE",
          "v": "283863a3-02dd-4c87-b4ae-2500a398fed4",
          "p": true
        },
        "ComplexItems": "_MachineEventQ, REPRM, TCTX, M_EXCP"
      },
      "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsPartnerReauthenticateActionHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.IsPartnerClientInvalidActionHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "PredicateResult": "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.NoOpHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "PredicateResult": "True"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Action",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.SSO.SSOSessionEndHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Action",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.SendErrorHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "RecorderRecord": {
        "Values": [
          {
            "Key": "SendErrorTechnicalProfile",
            "Value": "OAuth2ProtocolProvider"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Exception",
            "Value": {
              "Kind": "Handled",
              "HResult": "80131500",
              "Message": "We encountered an error connecting to the identity provider. Please try again later.",
              "Data": {
                "IsPolicySpecificError": false
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "Statebag": {
        "SE": {
          "c": "2019-11-29T11:07:31.6899756Z",
          "k": "SE",
          "v": "",
          "p": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Action",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.TransactionEndHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You should try setting up application insights logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom. You'll see the exact errors then

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I actually did implement insight but failed to understand the output. I'll update the question with insights result.

Comment: did you solved this? could you share the solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not, ended up using a simplet approach but it is something I'd like to get back to eventually

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving this error because the client ID I was passing to the identity provider was not authorized for the redirect URI I was sending to it. I had duplicated a custom policy and left the client ID for the original policy which, in the IDP, was authorized to redirect only to the original policy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error/symptoms with a different IDP but my root cause was different.  In my case, my B2C policy was sending token requests using GET instead of POST and the IDP server only supported POST.  To correct that, I had to set the following in the metadata section of my OAuth2 technical profile.

```
<Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

We also received this error and it was caused by the tenant configuration on the .net application initializing the call.

```
public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://{AzureADB2CHostname}/tfp/{Tenant}/";
```

In our case, the error was caused by the fact that we were using the tenant Id instead of the tenant domain as the Tenant

```
Tenant = "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com"
```